# Importing QtWidgets in Python on Windows Machine

Tags: windows-7, python, python3, anaconda, pyqt

I just installed PyQt5 in order to run an already written program, and it seemed that the installation was successful.  However when I try to import just the module QtWidgets within PyQt5, I receieve an error (See below).  Does anybody know what could be causing this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You have verified you are using a 64-bit version of QtWidgets?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I verify this?

Comment: Verify you downloaded and installed the 64-bit version of the module.

Comment: I just installed this using "pip install PyQt5", so I do not know what the default is.

Comment: I don’t either.  Still doesn’t chnage the fact I need to know what You installed

Comment: RELATED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip

Comment: This question has some potentially relevant answers as well - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019720/3395469